# Divider composable becomes invisible when placed inside composable with horizontalScroll modifier set. Is this a bug?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, compose-desktop, jetbrains-compose

### Background

I am making a desktop compose application.

I had a `LazyColumn` with `Divider` separating items. `LazyColumn`'s width may not fit in window so I made the `LazyColumn` horizontally scrollable by enclosing it inside a `Box` with `horizontalScroll()` modifier set.

Now `LazyColumn` became horizontal scrollable as well. But strangely the `Divider`'s separating the items disappeared.

After digging into it for a while, I figured out that `Divider`'s became invisible only when placed inside a horizontally scrollable parent.

---

### **Minimal Reproduction**

Here is a minimal reproduction of observed behavior where red `Divider` is clearly **invisible** when `horizontalScroll(rememberScrollState())` modifier is set in enclosing `Box`.

```
fun main() = application {
    Window(onCloseRequest = ::exitApplication) {
        Box(
            Modifier.fillMaxSize()
                .background(Color.Green)
                .horizontalScroll(rememberScrollState())
        ) {
            Divider(thickness = 10.dp, color = Color.Red)
        }
    }
}
```

[image: With horizontal scroll, divider is invisible!]

As it can be seen that the red `Divider` is **invisible** for above code.

---

**Expected Output:**

With `verticalScroll()` or no scroll modifier at all works fine as expected.

```
fun main() = application {
    Window(onCloseRequest = ::exitApplication) {
        Box(
            Modifier.fillMaxSize()
                .background(Color.Green)
                .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
        ) {
            Divider(thickness = 10.dp, color = Color.Red)
        }
    }
}
```

[image: As expected the divider is visible]

Correct output as expected, the red `Divider` is clearly **visible** for above code.

---

**Version info**

```
kotlin("jvm") version "1.5.21"
id("org.jetbrains.compose") version "1.0.0-alpha3"
```

---

I'd like to know if this is a bug? or is there a way to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**, this is not a bug.

`Divider` is used to take the full width, just like any other view with the `fillMaxWidth()` modifier.

But inside `horizontalScroll` this modifier is ignored because it is ambiguous: `horizontalScroll` wraps the size of the content, so the `maxWidth` constraint in this area is infinite.

From `fillMaxWidth` [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/package-summary#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).fillMaxWidth(kotlin.Float)):

> If the incoming maximum width is `Constraints.Infinity` this modifier will have no effect.

I haven't found any documentation mentioning `horizontalScroll` effects `Constraints`, you can see maintainer's answer on the [same issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/197332844#comment3), or you can test it by yourself like this:

```
Box {
    BoxWithConstraints(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        // output 1080 2082
        println("non scrollable max dimensions: ${constraints.maxWidth} ${constraints.maxHeight}")
    }
    BoxWithConstraints(Modifier.fillMaxSize().horizontalScroll(rememberScrollState())) {
        // output 2147483647 2082
        println("scrollable max dimensions: ${constraints.maxWidth} ${constraints.maxHeight}")
    }
}
```

---

In this case you need to specify the width explicitly, e.g:

```
Box(
    Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .background(Color.Green)
        .horizontalScroll(rememberScrollState())
) {
    var width by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
    val density = LocalDensity.current
    val widthDp = remember(width, density) { with(density) { width.toDp() } }
    LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier.onSizeChanged {
            width = it.width
        }
    ) {
        items(100) {
            Text("$it".repeat(it))
            Divider(
                thickness = 10.dp,
                color = Color.Red,
                modifier = Modifier.width(widthDp)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Note that when the top part of your `LazyColumn` is smaller than the bottom one, as in my example, the width will be smaller at first (to accommodate only the visible part), but after scrolling down and back up, the width will not be restored to its original width because the `Divider` width modifier will not let it shrink back down. If you need to prevent this, you need to calculate the `width' based only on the visible elements, which is more complicated.

Comment: Can you please provide source link which says fillMaxWidth is ignored inside horizontalScroll. Thanks for the info, upvoted.